# Lookml: Hide fields in production

Tags: liquid, looker, lookml

I'm trying to hide fields for when in production but keep them visible in the explore in dev.

I'm not sure how to go about it. Ideally there is an environment variable with the branch name I can grab from inside my view but I can't find anything in documentation.

Another option could be to create a variable but I get a lookML error when assigning the variable.

```
view: my_view {

  {% assign is_prod = "yes"  %}

  dimension_group: some_useless_field {
    hidden: {{ is_prod  }}

 }
```